# What's the best way to iterate through nested comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

My comment structure works like this (I'm using acts_as_commentable_with_threading).

Comment 1 (id: 1) has parent_id of nil because it is not a reply to any comment.
Comment 2 (id: 2) has a parent_id of 1 because it is a reply to comment 1 which has id of 1.
Comment 3 (id: 3) has a parent_id of 2 because it is a reply to comment 2.
Comment 4 (id: 4) has a parent_id of 1 because it is a reply to comment 1.

What is the best way of loading all the replies for a parent comment (in this case Comment 1). I could use multiple loops but I assume that would be really inefficient. For each reply, I would have to generate a partial to show that reply.

I would need a function that returns all of the children of a parent comment and the children of it's children, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading nested sets by multitple database queries is inefficient. There are better ways to organize nested data. Have a look at how you could implement a [nested set in SQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) or use a gem like [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) that allows to load all nodes with one query.

Comment: acts_as_commentable_with_threading uses awesome_nested_set.
How do I load all the nodes with one query? I couldn't find that in the documentation.

Comment: Found it. https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet